# SQL Grouping for Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am an amateur in learning, and I need some help.

I have one column with the following values that need to be grouped.

I have three groups of store numbers:

1. (001,002,003,004,005,006,012,014,007)
2. (111,112,113,114,115,116,121,122,123,317)
3. (261,262,263,264,271,273,274,275,276,277)

What I am trying to do is tell SQL to group them. So far all I have is:
IF [Store ID] = "006" THEN "HCFP"
END

How do I group more than one? and What is the correct way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I want all in group 1 to be named "HCFP". All in group 2 named "SFP" and Group 3 to be named "HFP"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case`.  In standard SQL, you can add a new column:

```
select t.*,
       (case when storeid in (001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 012, 014, 007)
             then 'HCFP'
             when storeid in (111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 121, 122, 123, 317)
             then 'SFP'
             when storeid in (261, 262, 263, 264, 271, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277)
             then 'HFP'
        end) as region
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the value, but this puts it on each output row.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for your reply, but I few questions and things I'd like to clarify. I have a column called StoreID. Those values were mentioned above and are grouped based on the 3 regions they are in. I want to create a new column containing the region data. If a cell has 262 then adjacent new column cell should say HFP.... I tried your code and it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

In Tableau, you can select your field in the left sidebar, the right click and select 'create group'. You can then select the values that you want to treat the same, press the group button and name your grouped values as desired. Then use the new group field in your visualizations.

When generating SQL, this will have the same effect as a hand crafted case statement.